# Custom Interactive Google Map

Tags: javascript, xhtml

I'm wanting to create a custom google map which has 2 locations.

Have been googling for quite a bit and can't find anything decent.

Any information is greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: You don't like the google maps documentation? It's almost only copy and paste from the doc for simple examples like that.

Comment: Thanks for the info Robin, would you mind posting a link to the documentation? I may be looking in the wrong area regarding what you're talking about.

Comment: ajwaka gave you the link already :) http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/basics.html Just create a map and take a look at how you should add markers, and you're done :)

Comment: Yes but as you'll read in my second comment the map needs to be interactive not just a static image - any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

I've successfully used the Google Static Maps API - here's an example from their api:
http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/staticmaps/#Markers

EDIT
From the API: markers=markerStyles|markerLocation1| markerLocation2|
just note that in the URL below %7C is |

Here's the URL showing how I added Camp Randall and the Kohl Center in Madison, WI 
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=Madison,WI&zoom=13&size=400x400&markers=color:blue%7Clabel:S%7C601+W+Dayton+St++Madison,+Wisconsin+53703%7C1440+Monroe+Street+Madison,+WI+53711&sensor=false

Comment: Wicked thanks a heap! Will let you know how I get on :-)

Comment: Ok I've read a bit more into this and I'm wanting to create a interactive map as such not just a static image. Any info? Users will need to be able to get directions and be able to view the map in more detail to reach their destination.